# Getting SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The let part of my code is producing an error I figured out why the bot wouldn't start by moving the client.login to the bottom new error includes it just spamming "Invalid Zip Code. Please follow the format: _weather <#####>" even if you put in the zipcode

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes("_weather") && message.author.bot === false)
        let zipCode = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    if (zipCode === undefined || zipCode.length != 5 || parseInt(zipCode) === NaN) {
        message.channel.send("`Invalid Zip Code. Please follow the format: _weather <#####>`")
            .catch(console.error);
        return;
    } else {
        fetch(`https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipCode},us&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(parsedWeather => {
                if (parsedWeather.cod === '404') {
                    message.channel.send("`This zip code does not exist or there is no information avaliable.`");
                } else {
                    message.channel.send(`

        The Current Weather
        Location: ${parsedWeather.name}, ${parsedWeather.sys.country}
        Forecast: ${parsedWeather.weather[0].main}
        Current Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        High Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_max - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        Low Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_min - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        `);

                }
            });
    }
});
client.login('token');
```

Comment: Would be helpful to paste the error

Comment: Correct Me If I'm wrong but it looks like your bots logs in every time a message is sent?

Comment: ```
let zipCode = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context
```is the error
& 
regards to the logging every time it sends a message... no? it only checks for the message "_weather"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use lexical declarations (`const` and `let`) after statements like `if`, `else`, `for` etc. without a block (`{}`). Use this instead:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    // declares the zipCode up here first
    let zipCode
    if (message.content.includes("_weather") && message.author.bot === false)
        zipCode = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    // rest of code
});
```

---

## Edit for 2nd question

You need to check if the message was sent by a bot so that it will ignore all messages sent by them, including the 'Invalid Zip Code' message:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.author.bot) return;
    // rest of code
});
```

Without that, the 'Invalid Zip Code' message would trigger the bot to send another 'Invalid Zip Code' message as 'Invalid Zip Code' is obviously not a valid zip code.

---

Also, change `parseInt(zipCode) === NaN` to `Number.isNaN(parseInt(zipCode))`. `NaN === NaN` is `false` for some reason in JS, so you need to use [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). You could also just do `isNaN(zipCode)` because [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) coerces its input to a number and then checks if it's `NaN`.

```js
console.log(`0 === NaN: ${0 === NaN}`)
console.log(`'abc' === NaN: ${'abc' === NaN}`)
console.log(`NaN === NaN: ${NaN === NaN}`)
console.log('')
console.log(`isNaN(0): ${isNaN(0)}`)
console.log(`isNaN('abc'): ${isNaN('abc')}`)
console.log(`isNaN(NaN): ${isNaN(NaN)}`)
console.log('')
console.log(`Number.isNaN(0): ${Number.isNaN(0)}`)
console.log(`Number.isNaN('abc'): ${Number.isNaN('abc')}`)
console.log(`Number.isNaN(NaN): ${Number.isNaN(NaN)}`)
```

---

## Edit 2

Try this code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.includes("_weather") && !message.author.bot) {
    let zipCode = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    if (zipCode === undefined || zipCode.length != 5 || Number.isNaN(parseInt(zipCode))) {
      message.channel.send("`Invalid Zip Code. Please follow the format: _weather <#####>`")
        .catch(console.error);
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(`https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipCode},us&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(parsedWeather => {
          if (parsedWeather.cod === '404') {
            message.channel.send("`This zip code does not exist or there is no information avaliable.`");
          } else {
            message.channel.send(`

        The Current Weather
        Location: ${parsedWeather.name}, ${parsedWeather.sys.country}
        Forecast: ${parsedWeather.weather[0].main}
        Current Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        High Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_max - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        Low Temperature: ${(Math.round(((parsedWeather.main.temp_min - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)))}° F
        `);

          }
        });
    }
  }
})
```

---

## Edit 3

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("_weather") && !message.author.bot)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick, but do you know why it spams https://gyazo.com/1b0b0daac4327d0bb8fcb1420f67e888
if you don't wanna click it the it's an ss showing that after typing the command the bot responds but then spam types "Invalid zip code. Please follow the format: _weather <#####>"

Comment: @ForgeMods I updated my answer. Next time please create a new question instead of asking another one in the same question.

Comment: I apologize @cherryblossom but um I got another one for this same question here now when I type it responds after every comment instead of only when someone does _weather do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @ForgeMods Sorry, that was a typo I made. Use `if (!message.author.bot)` (with the exclamation mark).

Comment: hmmm attempted to try the if (!message.author.bot) but for some reason the whole bot no longer works now the bot works without an exclamation point but responds to every comment someone makes in the discord @cherryblossom

Comment: @ForgeMods See my updated answer. I put all the code in the `if (message.content.includes("_weather") && !message.author.bot)` block, which I now realise was probably your intention.

Comment: when ever _weather is typed it goes off is there an option to make it so that only if it's _weather at the begging it'll go off, and that should be all thank you so much for your help

Comment: @ForgeMods Just use `message.content.startsWith("_weather")`.